# 2012 domain functional level with 2008 r2 web server

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

We are in the process of setting up a brand new domain and associated services (exchange, etc), on a new VMware environment. We want use Windows 2012 however the web-based ERP application requires 2008 R2 with IIS. Everything else (DC's, SQL, Exchange, Lync, Sharepoint, etc) will run fine on 2012.

There will be quite a bit of testing on this but due to outside constraints, we have to have this done asap but can't begin yet (yes it is for a gov't agency). So just looking for some guidance from ye ole serverfalut community.

Should we:

1. Not bother with 2012
2. 2012 DC's at 2008 r2 functional level
3. 2012 native domain with 2008 r2 webserver
4. Other

Please explain.

Comment: Kerry - don't forget to mark an answer, probably Rex's.

Comment: I will, I just want to wait until we execute, hopefully next week. Then I'll be sure to confirm! Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain level should have very little effect on a web server. Unless your ERP application has very deep hooks into active directory, you should be fine running your forest/domain at a 2012 functional level and having a 2008 R2 member server with IIS running your ERP app.

Comment: Thanks Rex! I was thinking the same thing. The ERP only uses AD to lookup users, their permissions and details are handled in the DB. The ERP fyi: http://www.newworldsystems.com/Public_Administration/index.asp

Answer (score 3):

C - there's absolutely no problem with having a domain *member* server running 2008 R2 in a domain that is running at 2012 functional level. None at all.